# I'm trying to prepend a div and load content in it with AJAX but the div remains empty

Tags: jquery, load, prepend

I'm trying to prepend a div and load content in it with AJAX but the div remains empty

```
$('#primary').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#primary').prepend('<div id="content"/>', function(){
            $('#content').load(link+' #content', function(){
                $('#primary').fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prepend` doesn't have a callback, it's an immediate change.  Try this:

```
$('#primary').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('<div id="content"/>').prependTo('#primary')
         .load(link+' #content', function(){
            $('#primary').fadeIn('slow');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.prepend` method doesn't take a callback, because it isn't asynchronous.

You can pass a function as the first argument, but it isn't as useful for prepending to only one element.

Here's your code fixed.

```
$('#primary').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    var content = $('<div id="content"/>'),
        primary = $(this);
    primary.prepend( content );
    content.load(link + ' #content', function(){
        primary.fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
$('#primary').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    var primary = this;
    $('<div id="content"/>')
        .prependTo(primary)
        .load(link+' #content', function(){
            $(primary).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});
```

The [`.prepend()` method](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) doesn't take a callback. I've used [`.prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) instead (which also doesn't take a callback) because it keeps the context so then the `.load()` call can be chained.